# how to pass a parameter and use that in my xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, msxsl

i have a xml file and a related xslt file. I am using msxsl.exe and i need to pass a parameter as a command line argument and use that in my xslt file.
how can i do that???

command:

```
msxsl.exe country.xml sheet.xslt -o country_sheet.html p1="india"
```

how to retrieve the value `india` in my xslt file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
<xsl:param name="p1" select="p1"/>
```

this would be outside any templates, acting somewhat like a global variable

yes then to use the contents of this you could use this inside a template

```
<xsl:value-of select="$p1"/>
```

Comment: thank you so  much.... after this line can i use $p1 in  for-each select="Root/Row[$p1]   statements na????????

Comment: my xml file contains a line <india>OK</india> so i am passing india as an argument. now i need to check if india==ok then some other lines..

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="$p1"/> i got this working. but i want use it in a if statement. <xsl:if test="india='OK'"> i need to change this line so as to include the $p1. As my xml file contains <india>OK</india>

Comment: Consider to post a sample of the XML you have, we would really need to see some context to help you with the specific code. You could try `<xsl:for-each select="Root/Row[*[local-name() = $p1] = 'OK']">...</xsl:for-each>` if you want a for-each to process all `Row` elements having a child element of the name the parameter `p1` has and where the value of that element is 'OK'. If that does not help then please add a sample of your XML input in your question.

Comment: @Martin Honnen - thank you so much... its working now.. with the same command....